# Irreducible polynomial of degree $5$ in $F_2 [x] $ has distinct roots in any algebraic closure of$ F2$

Tags: ring-theory

Is it true that any irreducible polynomial of degree $5$ in $F_2[x]$ has distinct roots in any algebraic closure of $F_2$?
$F_2$ : field of characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Finite fields are perfect, i.e. every finite extension is separable.

Comment: @lomberlego: Do you know what a separable extension is?

Comment: Yes, it is more or less that. More precisely, the algebraic closure of $\mathbf F_2$ is the direct limit of the inductive system of its finite extensions, which all have the form $\mathbf F_{2^d}$ (the order on the the set of indices is divisibility \ indeed, there exists a (transition) morphism from  $\mathbf F_{2^d}$ into \mathbf F_{2^e}$ if and only if $d\mid e$.

Comment: thanks a lot @ Bernard